# FormatException after parsing decimal

Tags: c#, parsing

I have a problem with this operation on one computer:

> string S1 = "000,00";
> decimal D1 = Decimal.Parse(S1);
>
> System.FormatException: (*)    in System.Number.StringToNumber(String
> str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo
> info, Boolean parseDecimal)    in System.Number.ParseDecimal(String
> value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)

It works on other computers.

I tried everything that came to my mind, among others :

> Decimal.Parse(S1, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

> Decimal.Parse(S1, new CultureInfo("pl-PL"));

> Decimal.Parse(S1, new CultureInfo("en-US"));

Changing ',' to '.'
Tried decimal.Parse, Double.Parse, double.Parse = the same problem.

Comment: _CultureInfo.CurrentCulture_ will give you the parsing for the culture enabled in the client PC.

Comment: Have you checked that they have the same .NET framework installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the similar problem some time ago. The options `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` and `NumberStyles.Any` solved the problem.

Providing the `InvariantCulture` causes parsing to use the ',' character as the thousands separator.
Providing `NumberStyles.Number` allows number format, which includes the AllowThousands option:

```
double.TryParse(Value, NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out result)
```

Comment: Yep, it worked. I think you were right with housands separator.